# SQL left join two tables independently

Tags: sql, left-join

If I have these tables:

```
Thing
id | name
---+---------
1  | thing 1
2  | thing 2
3  | thing 3

Photos
id | thing_id | src
---+----------+---------
1  | 1        | thing-i1.jpg
2  | 1        | thing-i2.jpg
3  | 2        | thing2.jpg

Ratings
id | thing_id | rating
---+----------+---------
1  | 1        | 6
2  | 2        | 3
3  | 2        | 4
```

How can I join them to produce

```
id | name    | rating | photo
---+---------+--------+--------
1  | thing 1 | 6      | NULL
1  | thing 1 | NULL   | thing-i1.jpg
1  | thing 1 | NULL   | thing-i2.jpg

2  | thing 2 | 3      | NULL
2  | thing 2 | 4      | NULL
2  | thing 2 | NULL   | thing2.jpg

3  | thing 3 | NULL   | NULL
```

Ie, left join on each table simultaneously, rather than left joining on one than the next?

[This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/468e48/5) is the closest I can get:

```
SELECT Thing.*, Rating.rating, Photo.src
From Thing
Left Join Photo on Thing.id = Photo.thing_id
Left Join Rating on Thing.id = Rating.thing_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the results you want with a union, which seems the most obvious, since you return a field from either ranking or photo.

Your additional case (have none of either), is solved by making the joins `left join` instead of `inner joins`. You will get a duplicate record with `NULL, NULL` in ranking, photo. You can filter this out by moving the lot to a subquery and do `select distinct` on the main query, but the more obvious solution is to replace `union all` by `union`, which also filters out duplicates. Easier and more readable.

```
select
  t.id,
  t.name,
  r.rating,
  null as photo
from
  Thing t
  left join Rating r on r.thing_id = t.id
union
select
  t.id,
  t.name,
  null,
  p.src
from
  Thing t
  left join Photo p on p.thing_id = t.id
order by
  id,
  photo,
  rating
```

Comment: Any way I can push the `union` down to a subquery? Also, I've added another row to my input - realized I missed a case

Comment: The missed case can be solved using left joins instead of inner joins. By using `union` instead of `union all`, the results will be filtered for duplicates, thus filtering out the duplicate rows with NULL, NULL for ranking and photo. Still no need for a subquery.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: The reason I'm after a subquery is that there are actually two tables in between `Thing` and `Photo`, and I'd prefer not to duplicate the join logic (`Thing join link1 on ... join link2 on ...`) in both places

Comment: Without that information there's no way for me to tell of course. But you might be able to move the union part with only the minimal required tables to a subselect and join that on the rest of the tables. I try to prevent that usually, since I think one or two extra joins is often more readable than having a big subselect, but in most cases it will be possible. But if you can't manage to get it working with the info you now have, you might better ask a new question that includes all that information.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT
  Thing.*,
  rp.src,
  rp.rating
FROM
  Thing
  LEFT JOIN (
    (
      SELECT
        Photo.src,
        Photo.thing_id AS ptid,
        Rating.rating,
        Rating.thing_id AS rtid
      FROM
        Photo
        LEFT JOIN Rating
          ON 1 = 0
    )
    UNION
    (
      SELECT
        Photo.src,
        Photo.thing_id AS ptid,
        Rating.rating,
        Rating.thing_id AS rtid
      FROM
        Rating
        LEFT JOIN Photo
          ON 1 = 0
    )
  ) AS rp
    ON Thing.id IN (rp.rtid, rp.ptid)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has no support for full outer joins so you have to hack around it using a `UNION`:

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3d2f/13

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Thing.*,
           Rating.rating,
           NULL AS photo
    FROM Thing
    LEFT JOIN Rating ON Thing.id = Rating.thing_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Thing.*,
           NULL,
           Photo.src
    FROM Thing
    LEFT JOIN Photo ON Thing.id = Photo.thing_id
) s
ORDER BY id, photo, rating
```

Comment: So is the ideal solution `LEFT JOIN (Photo FULL OUTER JOIN Rating ON 0) ON Thing.id IN (Photo.thing_id, Review.thing_id)`?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. The `UNION ALL` is a nice workaround though :)

Comment: If you would use `union` instead of `union all`, you wouldn't need the subquery at all. Also, this query will return duplicate rows if a Thing has neither a Rating nor a Photo.