# I have 3 table and need exclusive left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Table_1:

```
A
B
C
```

Table_2:

```
A | 4
B | 5
B | 6
C | 7
```

Table_3:

```
A | 7
B | 8
C | 9
```

Using 2 left joins I got this:

```
A | 4 | 7
B | 5 | 8
B | 6 | 8
C | 7 | 9
```

But I do group over the first column and 8 is accumulated twice, I wish to get:

```
A | 4 | _
A | _ | 7
B | 5 | _
B | _ | 8
B | 6 | _
C | 7 | _
C | _ | 9
```

I also wish to avoid `UNION ALL` because my first table is actually a complex query, I wish to avoid its recalculation.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d6012e281e3ba43487b1bfec85fd886c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that works without `UNION ALL`. For example, all answers here ([SQL left join two tables independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822489/sql-left-join-two-tables-independently))
work with it.

So, my solution is:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aa477308dee967690d0d8a2037b5a744)

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    b.val,
    NULL
FROM
    a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id

UNION ALL

SELECT
    a.id,
    NULL,
    c.val
FROM
    a
LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.id

ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

---

Edit: Found a way using [`GROUPING SETS`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-grouping-sets/):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=770bbb883cc3044d9f4e96114f7c288e)

```
SELECT
    ab.*,
    c.val
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.id,
        b.val
    FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((a.id), (a.id, b.val))
) ab
LEFT JOIN c ON ab.id = c.id AND ab.val IS NULL
```

Comment: @k06a Added a possible way without UNION

Answer (score 1):

I'll use `union all` , it's faster than join and clear ,why not use it?

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>   ("ID" varchar(1), "Val" int)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO Table1
>   ("ID", "Val")
> VALUES
>   ('A', 4),
>   ('B', 5),
>   ('B', 6),
>   ('C', 7)
> ;
> CREATE TABLE Table2
>   ("ID" varchar(1), "Val" int)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO Table2
>   ("ID", "Val")
> VALUES
>   ('A', 7),
>   ('B', 8),
>   ('C', 9)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select "ID","Val" as "Val1",null as "Val2" from Table1
> union all
> select "ID",null as "Val1","Val" as "Val2" from Table2
> order by "ID"
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Val1 | Val2
> :- | ---: | ---:
> A  |    4 | null
> A  | null |    7
> B  | null |    8
> B  |    5 | null
> B  |    6 | null
> C  |    7 | null
> C  | null |    9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d5971bbee1dc9b30b4a0f40023028f25)*

Comment: My first table is actually a complex query, I wish to avoid its recalculation.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the following https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cd0121bafe1bde6738bb8afc9a9f1970:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, t1.val, t2.val
FROM a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.id, b.val FROM b UNION ALL SELECT b.id, NULL FROM b) t1 on a.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.id, c.val FROM c UNION ALL SELECT c.id, NULL FROM c) t2 on a.id = t2.id and t1.val is null
WHERE t1.val IS NOT NULL
   OR t2.val IS NOT NULL
```

And got:

```
B  |  6  |  _
B  |  _  |  8
A  |  _  |  7
A  |  4  |  _
B  |  5  |  _
C  |  _  |  9
C  |  7  |  _
```

Wanna know others opinion.

Comment: Anyone know how to avoid duplicate line `B | _ | 8` without `DISTINCT`?

Comment: See my second solution: GROUPING SETS is the feature that does exactly this in principle.

Comment: @S-Man thanks, your ideas lead me to this solution, which helped me to boost my request from 12 minutes to 6 seconds :) https://explore.duneanalytics.com/queries/712/source#1184